# How to multiply variables in a string literal in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is an example:

```
var quantity: Int = 3
var price: Int = 20 
var total: String = "$quantity*$price"
```

But the the var total prints the following:

```
Output: 320
```

The desired outcome should be 60. In java, one would simply do a string literal like this to multiply price and quantity:

```
String price = "" + price*quantity
```

Comment: try `var total: String = "${quantity*$price}"`

Comment: You mean  "${quantity*price}" (without the dollar sign left of price. Yes it works thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `StringBuilder` might be also a good solution if you will need to `append()` or `insert()` to `total`

For example:

```
var quantity: Int = 3
var price: Int = 20
var total = StringBuilder().apply {
    append(price * quantity)
}
...
...
total.apply {
      insert(0, if (condition) "total amount:" else "current amount:")
}
// total amount: 60 or current amount: 60 depends on your condition
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

`var total: String = "${quantity*price}"`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar to this, but with adding the two together. It does appear this method will work with both adding and multiplication. Here is code form my app below:

```
val sampTonAdded = "${sublotTonEdit.toInt() + ranTonEdit.toInt()}"
```

It seemed as though adding `.toInt()` fixed my issues.